# Set a thin border using .css() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, border

So I am trying to get a border around buttons on my page when the user clicks them.

To set up the handler I am going:

```
$(".reportButtons").click(function(){ //change border color });
```

I have tried 2 ways to change the border color of the buttons in there. The first way is using the .css() function.

```
$(this).css({"border-color": "#C1E0FF", 
             "border-weight":"1px", 
             "border-style":"solid"});
```

But when I do it this way, the border is really fat (I want it to be hairline, like it normally would be if I set the width to 1px)

The other way I have tried is by downloading the jquery-color plugin, and doing something like:

```
$(this).animate({borderTopColor: "#000000"}, "fast");
```

When I do that, nothing happens. There is no error - just nothing happens. But if instead of trying to change the border color, I try to change the background color, it works fine....so am I using the jquery-color wrong? For reference, here is how I would change the background:

```
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#f6f6f6" }, 'fast');
```

like I said, that works. When I downloaded jquery-color, I only downloaded the one file (jquery-color.js), if that makes a difference....

So how do I go about getting a hairline border? (I would prefer to use the animate() method if you have anyideas how to get that to work)

Comment: did you mean `border-width`?

Comment: I'd recommend using a class instead of setting css properties.

Comment: @jrummell could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### Current Example:

You need to define `border-width:1px`

Your code should read:

```
$(this).css({"border-color": "#C1E0FF", 
             "border-width":"1px", 
             "border-style":"solid"});
```

### Suggested Example:

You should ideally use a class and addClass/removeClass

`$(this).addClass('borderClass');`
`$(this).removeClass('borderClass');`

**and in your CSS:**

```
.borderClass{
  border-color: #C1E0FF;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style: solid;
  /** OR USE INLINE
  border: 1px solid #C1E0FF;
  **/
}
```

jsfiddle working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gorelative/tVbvF/\

jsfiddle with animate: http://jsfiddle.net/gorelative/j9Xxa/
This just gives you an example of how it could work, you should get the idea.. There are better ways of doing this most likely.. like using a `toggle()`

Comment: Wow, that is REALLY slick. Why on EARTH does this not come up when I type "jquery change border color" or something similar into google?!?!?!?!!

Comment: i added a jsfiddle so you can see it in action

Comment: i added animate jsfiddle if you're curious

Comment: +1 since I always forget this, and always have to google only to get here again, and again!!!

Comment: @gorelative why dint you simply use `$(this).css({"border": "1px solid #C1E0FF"});` instead of calling all the attributes

Comment: @krishna shorthand is considered "bad practice" in todays practice.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend using a class instead of setting css properties. So instead of this:

```
$(this).css({"border-color": "#C1E0FF", 
             "border-width":"1px", 
             "border-style":"solid"});
```

Define a css class:

```
.border 
{ 
  border-color: #C1E0FF; 
  border-width:1px; 
  border-style:solid; 
}
```

And then change your javascript to:

```
$(this).addClass("border");
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe just "border-width" instead of "border-weight"? There is no "border-weight" and this property is just ignored and default width is used instead.

Answer (score 0):

After a few futile hours battling with a 
'SyntaxError: missing : after property id' message I can now expand on this topic:

border-width is a valid css property but it is not included in the jQuery css oject definition, so .css({border-width: '2px'}) will cause an error, 
but it's quite happy with .css({'border-width': '2px'}), presumably property names in quotes are just passed on as received.